# get every 4th hour

Tags: php

I have a time string from 0 to 24. like this

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
```

Now if it is 2 oclock, I want to select every 4th hour. so from above it will be

```
2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22
```

I am trying to wrap my head around it to get this going
thanks

I have tried this

```
if(range($hour, 23, 4)){
    print_r($hour);echo '<br />'; 
}
```

but it still prints all the hours in that array

**EDIT**
here is the code

`$hourlyData->hour` is just an hour digit, like 0 or 1 or 2 etc upto 23

```
foreach($jason->hours as $hourlyData){
    if(range($hourlyData->hour, 23, 3)){
        // print here to check if the correct time is used
        print_r($hourlyData->hour);echo '<br />'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use a "time string" for this? It's built-in. For an array:

```
$hours = range(2, 23, 4); // get every 4th hour starting from 2
```

And for a string:

```
$str = implode(', ', range(2, 23, 4));
```

Finally, to unlock the magic number elimination achievement:

```
define('HOURS_IN_DAY', 24);
$str = implode(', ', range(2, HOURS_IN_DAY - 1, 4));
```

Comment: ok but what if I am checking an array that has the number...so my code is something like foreach($hour as $hourlyData){
   
   if(range($hourlyData->hour, 23, 3)){
   print_r($hourlyData->hour);echo '<br />'; 
   
   }
   
   
  }

Comment: @Autolycus: That code doesn't make sense. Please edit the question with more information on what *exactly* you are doing.

Comment: You have to check if( in_array($value,range(2,23,4))

Comment: @Autolycus: Something simple `if($hour >= 2 && !(($hour - 2) % 4))` would work to match hours 2, 6, 10 etc. It's also a good idea to look up the operators and find out *why* it works.